# Overriding Routes for Asp.net Core within inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-3.1

I have this `BasicController<T>`
now i want to inherent that `BasicController<T>` for a specific type let us say `UserController`

**BasicController.cs**

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[Action]")]
public class BasicController<T> : Controller where T : BaseEntity
{
    [HttpGet('Get')]
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> Get() { return new List<T>();}
}
```

**UserController.cs**

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[Action]")]
public class UserController : BasicController<User>
{
    [HttpGet('Get')]
    public override IEnumerable<User> Get() { return new List<User>();}
    
    [HttpGet('GetOne')]
    public User GetOne() { return new User();}
}
```

i also use a routing convention so all classes that are `SomeEntity` get a separate controller of `BasicController<T>`

now the problem is when i do `GET` request it routes to `BasicController<T>` rather than `UserController`
how to fix or override the route ?

Comment: Shouldn't your endpoints inherit from ControllerBase and you should decorate the BasicController with ApiController Attribute.

Comment: Just don't do this... You win nothing by complicating everything by forcing inheritance in Controllers. Think of each Controller as an entirely separate piece of the application that should live on its own. If you *really* want to go down this path, remove all routing decorators from `BasicController<T>`